# own written JavaScript function named "reset"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp having 3 combos

```
            <select class="radius3" name="location" id="location" onchange="reset();">
            <option value="">Select Location</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
            <option value="23">C</option></select>

            <select class="radius3" name="wing" id="wing">
            <option value="">Select Wing</option>
            <option value="1">X</option>
            <option value="2">Y</option>
            </select>


            <select class="radius3"  name="post" id="post" >
            <option value="">Select Designation</option>
            </select>
```

and created a javaScript function named `reset` which is assigned to location combo on event onchange , so that on the change of location user have to explicitly select other values

```
function reset(){
     $("#wing").val("");
     $("#post").val("");

 }
```

but problem is that when ever i try to select any value from location combo it does not changes the value.

**P.S though its working fine in fiddle, please do not refer any fiddle
 and say its working fine,

### it is actually creating problem

**

[image: selecting option]

[image: after selecting option]

after selecting option its still showing the `select location`

> **Update**

I am using jquery-1.10.2

Comment: share this `showPosts()` function details.

Comment: If it works fine in a minimal fiddle, with the given code, then the problem is somewhere else. You either have an error message in your console or you have another important part of the code, that e.g. will run in your code immediately and in the js fiddle after everything is loaded.

Comment: can you add a alert message in the reset method and see whether it is getting called

Comment: it could be that there is some other method named reset in your global scope

Comment: check console for error, and check if the function is being called.

Comment: one easy way to check it is... open the developer tools console in the page and say `reset.toString()` check what is prented

Comment: Post the `showPosts()` function..

Comment: @t.niese I don't konw where i did a mistake, it really didn't work in a minimal fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/v070ffs3/1/

Comment: showPosts() has nothing todo with it, it was a rest service  which was getting posts on the basis on location and wing. thats it

Answer (score -1):

It works if it is using pure js.
Any Jquery library imported?

```js
function reset() {
  document.getElementById("wing").value = "";
  document.getElementById("post").value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <select class="radius3" name="location" id="location" onchange="reset();">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="23">C</option>
  </select>

  <select class="radius3" name="wing" id="wing" onchange="showPosts();">
    <option value="">Select Wing</option>
    <option value="1">X</option>
    <option value="2">Y</option>
  </select>


  <select class="radius3" name="post" id="post">
    <option value="">Select Designation</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using jquery-1.10.2.